# How to split a char* to integer tables in C

Tags: c

I have a char* like this "1 10 14 16"
I want to split it to integer array like 1,10,14,16...
how i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [strtol](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtol.html) in a loop, using explicitly its `endptr`  argument, something like:

```
char* pc = input_string;
char* end = NULL;
while (*pc) {
   long l = strtol (pc, &end, 0);
   if (end == pc) break;
   do_something_useful_with_the_number (l);
   pc = end;
}
```

if you want to accumulate all the numbers in an array, replace `do_something_useful_with_the_number (l);` with code growing that array (probably using `malloc` and/or `realloc` ...)

Comment: Doesn't strtol() need a base or does it default to 10?

Answer (score 1):

I would use strtok() like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[] = "1 10 14 16",
        *next = NULL;
   int number[10] = {0},
       noOfNumbers = 0,
       i = 0;

   next = strtok(string, " "); /* first call must have the string and delimiters */

   while ( next != NULL ) {
      number[noOfNumbers++] = atoi(next);
      next = strtok(NULL, " "); /* second call only the delimiters */
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < noOfNumbers; i++ ) {
      printf("number[%d] = %d\n", i, number[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

How you ensure the array of ints is big enough is left to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok` to separate the numbers and then use `atoi` on each of them to convert them to integers.

http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html

Answer (score 0):

```
int output[4];

char *input_string = "1 10 14 16";

sscanf(input_string, "%d %d %d %d", &output[0], &output[1], &output[2], &output[3]);

printf(" OUTPUT : %d %d %d %d\n", output[0], output[1], output[2], output[3]);
```

Above code should work

Regards

Comment: it it is 64 integer on char* how can I do?

Comment: Provided that your pattern is fixed.
If you do not know how many numbers will be there in your string then you have to use strtok as suggested by others...

Comment: Ohh you mean to say yo have 64 numbers in a string?
Then would suggest strtok as suggested by others
first strtok with space as delimiter and then use atoi or scanf

Answer (score 0):

1 you will have to a `strtok` to get one number string at a time.

2 Then you have todo `atoi` to convert a number string into an int.

This needs to be done till the loop condition of `strtok` returns a valid string

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        ///i is count *input_string[] times
        ///j is count temp[] times
        int main() {
            int i,j=0,num=0,*ptr,output;
            char temp[9]={'\0'};
            char *input_string[] = {"1 10 14 16 20 31 34 67 23 45 23"};

            for(i=0;*(*(input_string+0)+i)!='\0';)
            {
                switch(*(*(input_string+0)+i))
                {
                   case ' ':i++;break;
                   case '1':case '2':case '3':
                   case '4':case '5':case '6':
                   case '7':case '8':case '9':
                   case '0':
                       j=0;
                       while(*(*(input_string+0)+i) != ' ' || j>9 )
                       {
                            temp[j]=*(*(input_string+0)+i);
                            i++;j++;
                       }
                       j++;
                       temp[j]='\0';
                       output=atoi(temp);
                       ptr=malloc( sizeof(int) );
                       ptr=&output;
                       printf("%d ",*ptr);
                       break;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
I made small modifications.I updated the malloc (); function.May I ask whether the          condition?Thank you!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            ///i is count *input_string[] times
            ///j is count temp[] times
            ///num is count output[] times
            int main() {
                int i,j=0,num=0;
                int output[4];
                char temp[9]={'\0'};
                char *input_string[] = {"1 10 14 16"};

                for(i=0;*(*(input_string+0)+i)!='\0';)
                {
                    switch(*(*(input_string+0)+i))
                    {
                       case ' ':i++;break;
                       case '1':case '2':case '3':
                       case '4':case '5':case '6':
                       case '7':case '8':case '9':
                       case '0':
                           j=0;
                           while(*(*(input_string+0)+i) != ' ' || j>9 )
                           {
                                temp[j]=*(*(input_string+0)+i);
                                i++;j++;
                           }
                           j++;
                           temp[j]='\0';
                           output[num]=atoi(temp);
                           num++;
                           break;
                    }
                }
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)///print number
                    printf("%d ",output[i]);
                return 0;
            }

 ///*(*(input_string+0)+i) you can see is e.g char input_string[][];
```

Comment: What about more than 4 numbers in the input string?

Comment: also can. Why ? Because string array has a characteristic String to add after the '\ 0',So you can see in for loop "for(i=0;*(*(input_string+0)+i)!='\0';)", the judgment conditions "*(*(input_string+0)+i)!='\0'" if *input_string[] is not equal to '\0', the for loop continue i++.

Comment: *(*(input_string+0)+i) you can see is e.g char input_string[][];

Comment: No, if you have more than 4 numbers, you'll store some input number into `output[num]`  with `num>=4` and since you declared `int output[4];`  this is *undefined behavior*. In short, your program could crash in that case. In short, `output` should probably be heap-allocated with e.g. `malloc`